# Why locale won't work on my project?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, internationalization

Please let me explain what I've done first.

I installed the gem `rails-i18n` then I did rails g i18n es command
It generated translated_es.yml

Models names and their column names are in there so I translated like this.

Then I restarted my server to check if it applied, but it's not. why? I tried to submit a form with empty field.

I see validation error message, but the column name is in English. How can I fix this?

```
es:
  activerecord:
    models:
      acts_as_taggable_on/tag: acts_as_taggable_on/tag  #g
      acts_as_taggable_on/tagging: acts_as_taggable_on/tagging  #g
      acts_as_votable/vote: acts_as_votable/vote  #g
      comment: comentario  #g
      community: comunidad  #g
      [...]
```

Comment: Make sure that you do not have any tabs in .yml. Only you can use spaces

Comment: @Vinary Thanks! you mean tabs between column name and the value I typed?

Comment: In the whole .yml file you should not use tabs anywhere. Just use spaces inbetween. And the values would comes with single or double quotes

Comment: As you see my code I didn't use any single or double quoites. Is that why?

Comment: In the first three columns and values are same... so u dont need to mention it. The `comment: 'comentario'` and the `community: 'comunidad'`. Try this and let me know...

Comment: community comment and etcs

Comment: do you need to change the model name or the field names inside the models?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23370/discussion-between-vinay-and-husten)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
es:
  activerecord:
    models:
      community: "comunidad"
      comment: "comentario" 
    attributes:
      "community":
        title: "titulo"
      "comment":
        title: "titulo"
      [...]
```

Give two spaces for each and do not give tabs... Try and let know...

After edited you need to restart the server.

Comment: no What's your model name? you need to mention your model name instead of <model name>(you don't need the arrows)

Comment: I still get Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.
Please contact the server administrator, root@localhost and inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done that may have caused the error.
More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

Comment: @Vinary! one more thing that I want to ask you. If I put  "comunidad" after Model name, it gets error. But if I remove it, everything works fine.  However I cannot translate Model then. How can I solve?

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to switch you current locale. In case your project supports only one language you can put

```
I18n.locale = :es
```

into one of your initializers.

If this locale file are nested in some directory inside `config/locales` you should load nested directories inside `application.rb`

```
config.i18n.load_path += Dir[Rails.root.join('config', 'locales', '**', '*.{rb,yml}').to_s]
```

Comment: Internal Server Error
The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.
Please contact the server administrator, root@localhost and inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done that may have caused the error.

Comment: Are you sure this Internal Server Error is related to the i18n problem? What does the log output say when you start your server with `rails server`?

Answer (score 0):

Set the default, as well as the current language in your `config/application.rb`:

```
    config.i18n.default_locale = config.i18n.locale = :es
```